# link to create a user relationship type in views

Tags: views, users

I have user relationship, statuses and views installed. I created a view which shows "users online". I need to add a link to the view, that would allow other users to "create a relationship" with other online users via the view.

The user relationship I created is a one way relationship and there is no need for approval.

Thank you.

Comment: Hello. Is your problem on the link generation side, or relationship creation in code side?

Comment: I have not done any custom coding. I assumed this was taken care of via the user relationship module. Based on your question, I believe I need help with both. Thanks.

Comment: Looks like answer below shows that 1) it is already partially provided by relationships (how did I miss that?) and 2) how to code missing parts :) Try it, but looks solid on first glance or two.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help  you,

In Drupal 7, after configuration User relationship

- Create a php field using [**views php**](https://drupal.org/project/views_php) module and after enabling, add below code in **OUTPUT CODE** within **PHP tags**.

  ```
    global $user;
    $opt = '';
    $requestee_id = $row->uid;
    $requester_id = $user->uid;
    if (user_is_logged_in()) {
      if ($requestee_id != $requester_id) {
        //for friend request button
        $relationships = user_relationships_load(array('between' => array($requester_id, $requestee_id)));
        if (empty($relationships)) {
          $opt = l(t('Add Friend') , "relationship/$requestee_id/request/2", array('html' => TRUE, 'absolute' => TRUE, 'query' => array('destination' => 'user/' . $requestee_id), 'attributes' => array('class' => array('ur-link add-friend-btn user_relationships_popup_link'))));
        }
        else {
          foreach ($relationships as $relationship) {
            if ($relationship->approved == 1 && user_relationships_ui_check_access('view', NULL, $relationship)) {
              $opt = t('<span class="already-frnd">Friends</span>');
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    print $opt;
  ```

Note

- 2 is the **default USER relationship**.
- **Requester ID** - Who requested and **Requestee ID** - to whome the user is requested.

Make changes as per your requirement.

Comment: Thanks. I will need time to digest and implement this. (Not yet proficient at coding).

Comment: OK, ill give a brief explanation, user_relationships_load is a function which is used to load the relationship between requester and the Requestee. If relationship exist means there is a relationship between. If there is a relationship then     outputting the FRIEND text else returning the ADD FRIEND link.

Comment: For some reason, the actual code is being output. Am thinking its because nothing related to relationship is among the "available variables". Kindly assist further.

Comment: Hello, am still not able to get it to work. Please can you walk me through the steps? I added the above code as directed but did not get the desired result. Thanks.

Comment: First check the default relationship(friend) ID is 2 or not. Go to admin/config/people/relationships and hover edit link you will get the default relationship(friend) ID. And remove * from the "Add friend" link, I have given it for highlighting the default relationship ID. And also check the USER IDs($row->uid).

Comment: Thank you. I can now see the link in the view. The default is 1. However I am informed that " this user does not exist" when I select 'add friend'. Please what do you mean by "also check the USER IDs($row->uid)". Thanks.